# Instalador com autoscoll

Tags: php, jquery

Bom dia.
Estou criando um atualizador e preciso que fazer com que a cada `$rs` executado o scroll vá para baixo.

### O que acontece atualmente?

Fica uma tela branca, mas executando, e quando acaba mostra tudo de uma vez.

### O que gostaria:

Que foce executado cada `$rs`, mostrando seu `echo` e o scoll descendo automaticamente quando houver muitas linhas.

### Meu código atual

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
})
</script>

<div id="mostrar1"> Aguarde, atualizando banco de dados, não feche</div>

<?php
include("../conexao/conexao.php");

    $rs1 = $mysqli->query("UPDATE ...;");
    if (!$rs1) {echo "<font color=\"#CC0000\"> - Versão do site<br>";}else {echo "<font color=\"#00CC00\"> - Versão do site. Sucesso!</font><br>";}
    sleep(2);


    $rs2 = $mysqli->query("INSERT .... ;");
    if (!$rs2) {echo "<font color=\"#CC0000\"> - Insert erro<br>";}else {echo "<font color=\"#00CC00\"> - Insert sucesso!</font><br>";}
    sleep(2);

    .
    .
    .




    unlink("updateSQL_v423.php");
?>


<div id="mostrar2" class="display:none;"> Pronto! Banco de dados atualizado. APERTE F5, para recarregar a tela.</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#mostrar2').show();
    $('#mostrar1').hide();
})
</script>
```

Comment: O php só mostra o resultado final, ou seja, todos os textos apareceriam no final... O que pode ser feito é você fazer um jquer chamar um de cada vez e mostrar os resultados conforme forem sendo terminados, ai daria para fazer

Comment: @adventistaam como fazer para o jquery chamar um de cada vez?

Comment: você faz um backend em php, e na página chamaria com o jquery chamar as respectivas ações

Comment: @adventistaam Teoria estou ciente, mas na pratica, como fazer? ..rsrs

Comment: Você terá que trabalhar com ajax... pode fazer um exemplo para você ter uma ideia

Comment: Vai ajudar a ter um norte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um backend em php ter esse retorno,  já que o PHP retorna só quando está tudo pronto..

Segue a sugestão:

```js
var retorno = $('.retorno')
$('[botao]').on('click', function(){
     const aguarde = $('<p>Aguarde enquanto processamos seu pedido ...</p>')
     retorno.append( aguarde )
     setTimeout(()=>{
        update()
     },500)
     
})

function update(){
     const update = $('<p style="color=\"#CC0000\"">- Versão do site</p>')
     retorno.append( update )
     setTimeout(()=>{
       insert()
     }, 1500)
   
     
}


function insert(){
     const update = $('<p style="font color=\"#CC0000\"">- Insert erro</p>')
     retorno.append( update )
     setTimeout(()=>{
       done()
     }, 1500)
    
     
}

function done(){
     const update = $('<p> Pronto! Banco de dados atualizado. APERTE F5, para recarregar a tela</p>')
     retorno.append( update )
}
```

```html
  
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div class="retorno">
  </div>
  <button botao>Clique</button>
```

Funções javascript:

No caso função **update** seria assim:

```
function update(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'seuArquivo.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        id: 1,
        nome: 'Sei la',
        opcao: 'update'
      }
   }).done( result => {
       const update = $('<p style="color=\"#CC0000\"">'+ result.msg +'</p>')
       retorno.append( update )
       inserir()
   })
}

function inserir(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'seuArquivo.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        nome: 'Dado a inserir',
        opcao: 'inserir'
      }
   }).done( result => {
       const insert = $('<p style="color=\"#CC0000\"">'+ result.version +'</p>')
       retorno.append( insert )

       const done = $('<p> Pronto! Banco de dados atualizado. APERTE F5, para recarregar a tela</p>')
        retorno.append( done )
   })
}
```

No php **seuArqui.php**

```
$_opcao = $_POST['opcao']

switch($_opcao){
  case 'update':
      //Faça suas operações e retorne com echo json_encode
      $version = array('version' => '- Versão do site')
      echo json_encode( $version )
  break;
  case 'inserir':
     //Faça suas operações e retorne com echo json_encode
      $version = array('version' => 'Inserir result')
      echo json_encode( $version );
   break;
}
```

Então, essa é a sugestão.